# Refresh contents of div after loading with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a page laid out with 2 Div's on the page. The first Div works fine and loads a list of players. Now when you click on a link in that Div, it loads a second Div with information about that player. That too works fine, but what I want to do is have that second Div periodically refresh that players data after it being loaded by the click event. Here was my current attempt but it's not working:

```
var loc = "";
$("a").live('click', function() {
    loc = "player.php?user=" + $(this).html();
    $("#result").load(loc);
});
setInterval(function() {
    $("#results").load(loc);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What specifically is "not working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `setInterval` inside the `click` event handler so that it doesn't fire off before the first click and you ensure the `loc` is defined before the first interval completes.

Also, you may have a typo within your `setInterval`, as it refers to `$('#results')`, not `$('#result')`. One or the other is likely incorrect.

Finally, it's good practice to assign a `setInterval` to a variable, so that you can clear it later, if needed with `clearInterval`. it also lets you set the interval just once, rather than every time the user clicks

```
var loc = "";
var interval = null;

$("a").live('click', function(){
    loc = "player.php?user=" + $(this).html();

    $("#result").load(loc);

    // only create the interval once
    if(!interval) {
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            $("#result").load(loc);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well I would upvote but I don't have the rep for it. It's working now. It was that simple typo that I missed. Such simple things can cause such big grief. And it doesn't matter if the refresh happens before the click event, it will just be an empty div, which is OK for my situation.

Comment: @JosephJ: If jackwanders pointing out the typo is what answered your question, then whilst you can't upvote yet you can accept the answer by clicking the tick next to it, which will gain you a little rep and move you closer to voting.  More information can be found: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the url to loc in click event of anchor `a` which would be loading the contents but the other case of setInterval which is executed on load the loc will not have the url. So assign url to loc the time you declare it or make sure it is assigned before setInterval.

Also note `live` is deprecated you should use `on` instead.

```
var loc = "player.php?user=" + $("a").html();
$("a").live('click', function(){
        loc = "player.php?user=" + $(this).html();
        $("#result").load(loc);
    });
setInterval(function(){
    $("#results").load(loc);
}, 1000);
```